# Bulk insert/update using Stateless session - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a requirement to insert/update more than 15000 rows in 3 tables. So that's 45k total inserts.

I used Statelesssession in hibernate after reading online that it is the best for batch processing as it doesn't have a context cache.

```
session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession;
for(Employee e: emplList) {
  session.insert(e);
}
transcation.commit;
```

But this codes takes more than an hour to complete.

Is there a way to save all the entity objects in one go?
Save the entire collection rather than doing it one by one?

Edit: Is there any other framework that can offer a quick insert?

Cheers!!

Comment: Have you tried `hibernate.order_inserts` and `hibernate.order_updates` with simple Session? And could you show what SQL statements are executed when you save one Employee?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you've set the hibernate property:

`hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`

So that Hibernate can batch these inserts, otherwise they'll be done one at a time.

Comment: I tired this with the normal session and it still takes the same amount of time or close.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to insert all entities in one go. Even if you could do something like `session.save(emplList)` internally Hibernate will save one by one.

Accordingly to Hibernate User Guide StatelessSession do not use batch feature:

> The insert(), update(), and delete() operations defined by the StatelessSession interface operate directly on database rows. They cause the corresponding SQL operations to be **executed immediately**. They have different semantics from the save(), saveOrUpdate(), and delete() operations defined by the Session interface.

Instead use normal Session and clear the cache from time to time. Acttually, I suggest you to measure your code first and then make changes like use `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`, so you can see how much any tweak had improved your load.

Try to change it like this:

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
int count = 0;
int step = 0;
int stepSize = 1_000;
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(Employee e:emplList) {
    session.save(e);
    count++;
    if (step++ == stepSize) {
        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        long linesPerSecond = stepSize / elapsed * 1_000;
        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
        msg.append("Step time: ");
        msg.append(elapsed);
        msg.append(" ms Lines: ");
        msg.append(count);
        msg.append("/");
        msg.append(emplList.size());
        msg.append(" Lines/Seconds: ");
        msg.append(linesPerSecond);
        System.out.println(msg.toString());
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        step = 0;
        session.clear();
    }
}
transcation.commit;
```

About `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` - you can try different values, including some very large depending on underlying database in use and network configuration. For example, I do use a value of 10,000 for a 1gbps network between app server and database server, giving me 20,000 records per second.

Change `stepSize` to the same value of `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`.

Comment: So basically you are saying I can't reduce the time taken for these many inserts. Is there any other framework that offers something like this?

Comment: No. Because it is jdbc based.

Comment: You can make it faster with batch jdbc batch inserts. Just use a normal Hibernate Session and change the `hibernate.jdbc_batch_size`.

Comment: I tried this. It still takes almost the same time as using stateless session insert.